# How does convolution with Gaussian, What properties are retained?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $V$ and $U$ be two independent random variables where $U$ is a Gaussian random variable
\begin{align}
W_1&=V+U, \text{where $V$ is a continuous distribution with infinit support },\\
W_2&=V+U, \text{where $V$ is a continuous distribution with finite support  $|V|\le c$ },\\
W_3&= V+U, \text{where $V$ is a discrete distribution with finitely many points },\\
W_4&= V+U, \text{where $V$ is a discrete distribution with finitely many points with restriction to $|V| \le c$},\\
W_5&= V+U, \text{where $V$ is a discrete distribution with countably many points},\\
W_6&= V+U, \text{where $V$ is a discrete distribution with countably many points with $|V| \le c$}\\
W_7&= V+U, \text{where $V$ is a dist. with uncoutably many points supported on a set of Leb. measure $0$}
\end{align}

Because of the convolution with Gaussian $W_i$ has a continuous random variable with infinite support in particular the pdf of $W$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_{W_i}(w)=E[ f_U(V-w)].
\end{align}

My questions is:  are there 'any' fundamental difference between  $f_{W_i}$'s that are consequence what the distribution of $V$ is? Or does convolution with Gaussian 'blurs all' the differences.

Comment: Did you mean infinitely many or perhaps countably many for $W_4$? As it stands, it seems $W_4$ is the same case as $W_3$.

Comment: @MarkFischler I want to distinct cases when you put restriction  on where your points can be and the case where you do not. Otherwise, they are the same.

Comment: I can't read the end of the definition of $W_7$. Can't you just have the math parts in math and leave the rest as plain text, instead of putting everything into an `align` environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "deconvolution" to recover $V$ from $W$.  In terms of the characteristic function, $\varphi_{W}(t) = \varphi_U(t) \varphi_V(t)$, and $\varphi_U(t) = \exp(i\mu t - \sigma^2 t^2/2)$ is known, so $\varphi_V(t) = 
\exp(-i\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2/2) \varphi_W(t)$.  Thus e.g. if $\varphi_V(t)$ is a trigonometric polynomial, you are in case (3).  If $\varphi_V(t)$ is an entire function of exponential type and square-integrable over horizontal lines, then you are in case (2).